# Update object in MongoDB array if the value matches or add the object in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a testResult collection where I am storing User's answers of test

`answers` is an array of object with stores `questionIndex` and `optionIndex` and then during the time of score calculation I check if the `optionIndex` is correct or not
This is how the document looks like:

```
{
  "isCompleted": false,
  "score": 0,
  "answers": [
    {
      "questionIndex": 1,
      "selectedOptionIndex": 1,
    },
    {
      "questionIndex": 1,
      "selectedOptionIndex": 0,
    },
    {
      "questionIndex": 2,
      "selectedOptionIndex": 0,
    },
    {
      "questionIndex": 3,
      "selectedOptionIndex": 0,
    },

  ],
}
```

As you can see there are two answers for the `questionIndex: 1`
What I want is if the `questionIndex` is already present in the array the value of `selectedOptionIndex` should be updated. If it is not present it should be added. And the array is empty in the starting so cannot compare the `questionIndex` right from the beginning. I am using mongoose.